# Auto Detect Time and Change DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when the page is loaded I want my drop down list to change the value according to the time.

For example, if I was to open the page at 13:27 it should show 14:00 in the dropdown list.

If I was to open the page at 10:07 is should show 11:00 in the dropdown list.

How can this be done in Javascript/jQuery.

I've had a look at get Time/getElementbyID('date').value =Date(); but couldn't understand it.

I want it just how nationalxpress done it.
http://www.nationalexpress.com/home.aspx

```
<select id="leavedrop">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        <option>00:00</option>
        <option>01:00</option>
        <option>02:00</option>
        <option>03:00</option>
        <option>04:00</option>
        <option>05:00</option>
        <option>06:00</option>
        <option>07:00</option>
        <option>08:00</option>
        <option>09:00</option>
        <option>10:00</option>
        <option>11:00</option>
        <option>12:00</option>
        <option>13:00</option>
        <option>14:00</option>
        <option>15:00</option>
        <option>16:00</option>
        <option>17:00</option>
        <option>18:00</option>
        <option>19:00</option>
        <option>20:00</option>
        <option>21:00</option>
        <option>22:00</option>
        <option>23:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, update the option tags to have a value

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="0">00:00</option>
<option value="1">01:00</option>
<option value="2">02:00</option>
...
```

After that, here is a javascript code to get the current time and select the option accordingly:

```
var hourToSelect = new Date().getHours() + 1;
if(hourToSelect === 24) hourToSelect = 0;

$("option[value='" + hourToSelect + "']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: From the code above, you should be able to extend it. At least it is a starting point...